# Count consecutive repeated patterns in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Given a list such as:

```
6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6,5,5,5,6,4,6,1
```

I want a way to split the list based on the patterns, in the following way:

`{6,4,6,4,6},{5,5,5},{6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6},{5,5,5},{6,4,6,4,6,4,6,4,6},{5,5,5},....,{5,5,5},{6,4,6},{1}`

And I want to do it in a general way. The goal is to have a recursive sublength following another pattern, namely the sub-length of the above list is

```
5,3,9,3,9,3,9,3,...,
```

Then I would like to split it gain into `{5},{3,9,3,9,3,9,...}`

The problem that I am working on will only contain two patterns i.e. a sequence of alternating numbers {a,b,a,b,...} or a sequence of repeated numbers {c,c,c,...}.

Comment: You ***MUST*** specify what you consider a segmentable pattern... otherwise this question is meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6,
        4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 
        5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
        5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
        4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
        4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 
        4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
        4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 
        5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
        5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
        4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 1};
```

Using `SequenceSplit`:

```
SequenceSplit[list, s : {PatternSequence[6, 4] .., 6} :> s]
```

> {{6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5,
> 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5,
> 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5,
> 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5,
> 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6}, {1}}

Finally, using `Tally`:

```
Tally[%]
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing at your patterns...

```
init = {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 
6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 
5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 
6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 
6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 
6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 1};

SequenceSplit[
  init, 
  {alternater : {PatternSequence[x_, y_] .., x_} :>  Length[alternater], 
   repeater : {z__} :> Length[repeater]}]
```

There could be unexpected results if these aren't your patterns or if these patterns aren't exhaustive.

Comment: For some reason this runs super slow on my machine. Is it costly to parse like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6,
    4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 
   5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
   5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
   4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
   4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 
   4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
   4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 
   5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
   5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
   4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 6};

f1[k_List] := 
 Split[k] /. {a_} :> a  // 
  SequenceReplace[#, g : {Except[_List] ..} :> g] &

f1@list
```

> {{6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5,
> 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5,    5},
> {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5,    5},
> {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5,    5},
> {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4,
> 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {6, 4, 6}}

```
list // f1 // Map[Length]
```

> {5, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9,
> \ 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 3}

does not immediately conform to the `The problem that I am working on will only contain two patterns` assertion so only a custom solution would be feasible instead of a recursive one.